# SSAS. Long time processing in second time with ProcessFull

Tags: ssas

I use ProcessFull parameter for processing one of my dimension. First time processing took 45 min. But second time it takes an hour or even more.

Why second processing takes more time than first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesnt sound like normal SSAS behaviour.  I would suspect some external factor.